# Show current standby value from hdparm

Tags: debian, hard-disk, power-management, hdparm

[hdparm](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) allows me to set the time before the disk went to standby using the `-S <value>` flag. But how can I set what value is *currently* configured for standby?

I tried

```
# hdparm /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 multcount     =  0 (off)
 IO_support    =  1 (32-bit)
 readonly      =  0 (off)
 readahead     = 256 (on)
 geometry      = 972801/255/63, sectors = 15628053168, start = 0

# hdparm -S /dev/sda
  -S: bad/missing standby-interval value (0..255)
```

In `/etc/hdparm.conf` is nothing configured, everything is commented out. Does this mean that standby is completely disabled by default? Or is there some default value set by the hard disk drive manufactor, which applys when nothing customized is configured using `hdparm`?

According to the docs, I assumed that this could be fetched using the `-B` switch:

```
# hdparm -B /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 APM_level      = 164
```

Since values from 1 to 240 specify multiples of 5 seconds, this means 165 * 5 = 825s (~14 Min). To verify, I set the standby value to 126

```
# hdparm -S 126 /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 setting standby to 126 (10 minutes + 30 seconds)
```

But `APM_level` is still unchanged to 164, so I assume that this is not the current standby value. Seems to be some other technology for energy saving.

Comment: Does this reply https://askubuntu.com/questions/252039/how-can-i-find-out-the-current-drive-spin-down-time ?